# SWF (using XML) only working locally, not on home server or web hosting server

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, flash

I use a main SWF file, which has some animations. It uses xml from a .php file which specifies several items, e.g. images and other SWFs to be used in the main SWF. Locally everything works perfectly, but when invoking it via my home server, or hosting provider it doesn't work anymore and I don't get why. All links are relative and correct. Somehow the main SWF doesn't load fully, or has problems with the XML from the .php file. I'm not sure, now I only get a black box that doesn't show any of the other content it's supposed to.
check it out: http://xxxxxxx.ath.cx/cc-common/templates/dynamiclead/dynamic_leadee.swf

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><dynamic_content>
    <item 
 blurb="Text 1" 
 content_url=""  
 content_source="" 
 content_timer="8000" 
 content_target="_self"
 tab_color="0x000000"
 tab_border_color="0x000000" 
 tab_arrow_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_text_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_image="/template/images/dle_TOPmay06.jpg" 
 cycle="true" 
 content_border_color="0x" 
 content_bg_image="" 
 tab_hl_color="0x000000" 
 tab_highlight_color="0x" 
 tab_highlight_text_color="0x" 
 tab_highlight_image="" >
</item>
<item blurb="Text 2" 
 content_timer="5000" 
 cycle="true" 
 content_border_color="0x" 
 content_bg_image="" 
 tab_hl_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_border_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_arrow_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_text_color="0xFFFFFF" 
 tab_image="/template/images/dle_MIDandBOTmay06.jpg" 
 tab_highlight_color="0x" 
 tab_highlight_text_color="0x" 
 tab_highlight_image="" 
 content_url="" 
 content_source="" 
 content_target="_self" >
</item>
<item blurb="Text 3" 
    content_timer="5000" 
    cycle="true" 
    content_border_color="0x" 
    content_bg_image="" 
    tab_hl_color="0xFFFFFF" 
    tab_border_color="0xFFFFFF" 
    tab_color="0xFFFFFF" 
    tab_arrow_color="0xFFFFFF" 
    tab_text_color="0xFFFFFF" 
    tab_image="/template/images/dle_MIDandBOTmay06.jpg" 
    tab_highlight_color="0x" 
    tab_highlight_text_color="0x" 
    tab_highlight_image="" 
    content_url="" 
    content_source="" 
    content_target="_self" >
</item>
</dynamic_content>
```

this works like a charm when invoking the main SWF locally.
The ActionScript from the main sWF can be found at samedomain as above/Actionscript_mainmovie.txt

This also seems to work great. the function formattabs (line 68) uses some javascript. Locally the main SWF functions even without this hbx file which is located
/cc-common/wss/hbx.js and use in the webpage actually.
I haven't got a clue what's keeping the main SWF from working properly, because all other single SWFs work properly when invoked using a direct link. And this one just isn't working... Do I maybe need to add something in the php.ini file??
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was an idiot:
the xml code goes into an .xml file and the .php requires php... So I created a file with everything I need like links, colors etc for the SWF and then .php generates the xml output which the SWF can now properly use.
I actually put the xml directly into the .php....